# Por que o SQLSERVER Express não reconhece palavras acentuadas ao criar banco utilizando o sqlcmd?

Tags: sql-server-express

**Problema**

Em alguns bancos(SQLSERVER) eu estou precisando frequentemente popular as tabelas com alguns dados, que normalmente vem de um arquivo `.txt` ou `.xlsx`, preciso fazer isso da forma mais rápido possível.

A primeira coisa que pensei em fazer que iria me ajudar, foi copiar os dados desses arquivos para o excel, salva-los como `.csv` e  importar no banco indo em `banco de dados -> tarefas -> importar arquivo simples`, porém desta forma as letras quem vem com acento não são reconhecidas pelo SQLSERVER e são substituídas por `?`.

A segunda coisa que pensei em fazer foi: copiar os dados dos arquivos `.txt` ou `.xlsx`, ir em `tabela_do_banco -> Editar 200 linhas superiores` e colar lá. Desta forma as letras que contem acento são reconhecidas e exibidas sem 
 serem substituídas.

Entretanto, o problema em fazer desta segunda forma é o seguinte: depois de tudo pronto eu preciso criar o banco utilizando o comando `sqlcmd -E -S .\sqlexpress -i "%CD%\script.sql"` e quando eu faço isso os dados que anteriormente foram populados sem nenhum carácter ser substituído são substituídos :(.

**Dúvidas**

- Por que o SQLSERVER Express não reconhece palavras acentuadas ao criar banco utilizando o sqlcmd ?
- O que eu poderia fazer para que o SQLSERVER Express reconheça os carácteres que contém acentos(á, à, ã, â, **ç**) ?

Comment: Já até instalei a versão mais recente do Sql Server 2019 e criei o banco com a collate `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8` e acontece a mesma coisa: se eu gero o script de criação do banco e executo ele pelo próprio SSMS o banco é criado normalmente sem substituir os carácteres, porém se eu uso o comando do `sqlcmd` para executar o arquivo de script que contém a criação do banco; ele cria o banco com a collate que eu defini mas substitui os carácteres que tem acento por outros estranho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolução para o primeiro problema**

Para mudar o `encode` do arquivo `*.csv` bastava:

- Abrir ele como bloco de notas
- Selecionar a opção `Salvar como`
- Alterar a codificação para `UTF-8`(Em um combo-box que fica ao lado do botão salvar)
- Salvar o arquivo e substituir, caso salve com o mesmo nome;

**Resolução para o segundo problema**

No comando `sqlcmd` bastava adicionar a flag `-f 65001`.
Onde `-f` especifica o codepage e `65001` representa o `UTF-8`

**OBS:** Gerei o script sql com a codifição `UTF-8` pré-definida e tentei rodar o `sqlcmd` sem passar a flag `-f`, porém a codificação não foi mantida.